# Return first element in a custom selected row

Tags: excel

I have a column called "Time elapsed" which calculates the time difference between the found date (under mon, tue, wed....) and the request date. Each row in the "Time elapsed" column will search the corresponding row between Mon to Tue (Week after) and return the first element it finds. How do I go about doing this? I tried an index match and also looked into array referencing, but I am not familiar enough with the syntax to get it to work. A picture of a sample of the spreadsheet is posted.

Thanks guys.

[image: spreadsheet sample]

Comment: where does "the request date" data located?

Comment: My mistake, its right before the Mon Column. I have already solved it. I just had to use the small function to return the first element.

Comment: appreciate if you may share the solution (post as answer) for the benefit of future readers. /(^_^)

Answer (score 0):

If range(B1:E1) contained the date information in which you wanted to return and range(A1) contained the request date. The difference between the first instance (earliest date) found in the range and the request date can be found using:

=SMALL(B1:E1,1)-A1